# Is it possible to perform search with $O(\sqrt{N})$ copies of a "resource" state rather than an oracle?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

Suppose that we wish to find $x$ s.t. $f(x) = 1$. Instead of having access to an oracle like $U_f: |i\rangle \mapsto (-1)^{f(i)}|i\rangle$ or $U_f: |i\rangle|z\rangle \mapsto |i\rangle|z\oplus f(i)\rangle$, suppose we have access to copies of a state prepared using the oracle in a simple way, e.g.
$\sum_i (-1)^{f(i)}|i\rangle$ or $\sum_i |i\rangle|f(i)\rangle$.

Is there a way to use these states to perform a search algorithm that uses $O(\sqrt{N})$ copies of the state, where $N$ is the size of the search space (the range of values $i$ can take)?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Intuitively, we don't use properties of the oracle $U_f$, we're just making a quantum tomography of a state which equals $|\psi_f\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_i (-1)^{f(i)}|i\rangle$ for some $f$ (and there are $N$ possible $f$).

Let's also denote $|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_i |i\rangle$.

One can use the [proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9711070) of Grover's algorithm optimality to derive the bound on the number of copies needed for tomography.

There is an inequality which gives

$$
2N-2\sqrt{N}\sqrt{p} - 2\sqrt{N}\sqrt{N-1}\sqrt{1-p} \le 
$$
$$ 
\le \sum_f ||\psi_{f}\rangle^{\otimes K} - |\psi_{0}\rangle^{\otimes K}|^2,
$$

for the average success probability $p$ of determining $f$ from $K$ copies of $|\psi_{f}\rangle$.

But
$$
\langle \psi_0 | \psi_f \rangle = \frac{N-2}{N},
$$
and
$$
||\psi_{f}\rangle^{\otimes K} - |\psi_{0}\rangle^{\otimes K}|^2 = 2-2{\rm Re}\langle \psi_0 | \psi_f \rangle^K,
$$
so that
$$
2N - 2\sqrt{N} \le N(2 - 2 (\frac{N-2}{N})^K),
$$
if we want $p$ to be close to 1.

Thus
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \ge (\frac{N-2}{N})^K \ge 1-\frac{2K}{N} ,
$$
hence
$$
K \ge (N-\sqrt{N})/2,
$$
which means the complexity is $O(N)$ at least.

Comment: How does one prove that the tomography you describe is the optimal method for finding $i$ such that $\langle i| \psi_f\rangle = 1$?

Comment: The proof of the inequality is in the appendix of that paper. Essentially, for a tomography we can't do anything better than a von Neumann measurement in some enlarged Hilbert space.